# Track lighting + ceiling pancake box? Is there an available solution?

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling

So earlier today, I went to replace my ceiling light fixture with a cheap-o track light set from Ikea. When I went to mount the track base, I was visited by the ghost of when I first moved into the house, as the box in the ceiling is a pancake box.

The Ikea set won't "fit" using the pancake box, because there is simply not enough room to fit the wiring:

[image: I hate this house construction, and myself]

I have been looking at track lighting solutions with modular H track to see if I could get one of them to work, but everything for installation for any of them is written assuming you haev a full-depth box. Does anyone have any suggestions for a track solution that would work with this box? (I am not the handiest person on the planet.)

Comment: An extension ring is the easy solution **if** you are OK with the entire track fixture hanging down from the wall an inch or two.

Comment: How close is it to fitting? The Ideal In-Sure 2-port connectors are the smallest listed wire connectors I know of. If you're really close to fitting it's possible they could get you there if you swapped out the wire nuts for them.

Comment: @KMJ Not close enough that I'm confident in that, but I am probably going to get some of those connectors for whatever I end up doing here anyway. The wire bundle coming through the breakout is a significant problem in that getting that to route in a friendly way is proving to be problematic. The box is 1/2" deep, and it looks like the In-Sures are 3/8", so it's probably worth a shot? The fixture I removed had around an inch-deep "pan" as part of the fixture mount where I could stash the wires and I'm missing that right now.

Comment: Remember that you only need 6 inches of free conductor. See how much you have, and you can trim back the jacket a little and take the wires to minimum length. This is going to be one of those installs where every little bit matters.

Comment: Why not just move the box? That's probably mounted to the bottom of a joist. Unscrew the box, see which side the wires come in from, cut a hole for a new box on that side of the joist, then attach the new _deep_ "old work" box there. Patch up the existing bit of hole in the ceiling (a traditional light would probably be large enough to cover the hole, the track light wouldn't), then you have all the wiring room you could possibly want!